# My site has crashed .. anyone have some info?

Tags: ftp

I booked a domain name for my website from a hosting provider .I gave the domain name , along with ftp details to a freelancer to develop the site in wordpress . the freelancer developped and he got full payment , and the site and site was working fine ,etc ..
  From that time , I did not change the admin logging as well as ftp details , this means that such info is still known to the freelancer ..
  A week ago , I found that some links in my site was not working .. I sent him a mail about this , and he said that he will fix it if i give him ftp details . and I did so , next I found that the entire site is gone . then he sent me a mail , without I asked him , and he he said that there have been someone who got access to my server , and he removed all files of my site and he installed drupal instead .and that he can rebuild the site in one day , by charging a full fee of 250 usd again ..
  Can anyone know what I can do in this situation , to find who did such act , could it be the host provider or that freelancer ,, and if there is a possibility to have my site back top the server ..
 I will appreciate any info on this..
Regards ,
Thanks

Comment: It sounds to me like the freelancer is scamming you. Unfortunately, if you didn't back up the site, there really isn't any way to restore it, unless the host you go through provides a back up service that was in place prior to the files being deleted. As far as what you can do from here, if you don't own the equipment that it was hosted on, you really don't have any options other than to rebuild the site.

Answer (score 2):

hey first, go and change your ftp username and password and all other passwords like the domain admin ones and the hosting account ones. then delete any existing databases. and then check for backups if any available on your server. if its there, take it down but don't install it cause the freelancer will again have access to your wordpress admin. install wordpress on your hosting. go to wordpress.org to know more about how to install and to download. then if you have backups, import your themes and plugins. and if you don't have and cannot make the site on your own, please don't go back to that same freelancer. cause again he'll do this. find someone else, more reliable, it'll be good if he's your friend or something. then make a new ftp account on your hosting, and give those credentials to him not your admin ones. copy whatever he makes to a new folder and afterwards download it for backups. it'll be best if you can make the site on your own. please dont trust anyone with your site, cause thats one of your main identities. but first change your passwords.

Answer (score 1):

also, when you change your password, check if you saved passwords in ftp client (ie. total commander, or filezilla). some of the trojan/viruses can steal passwords, and made a mess.

it's not ok to say that freelancer is the one that made that damage.

Answer (score 0):

The freelancer is scamming you. Agree with him and ask him to put the site back on, then change your ftp info etc and stop communicating with the freelancer. (If necessary pay him 50% of the money to get him to install the site again).

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, change all of your passwords, and see if your host has backups that you can use. If not, you're a bit out of luck; the freelancer is scamming you. Make sure to create an FTP account that isn't admin account, and limit its access to only places where you need editing, then give the account credentials to a trustworthy person. Get someone else to remake the website, if you are seriously out of luck without backups.